# Checking for a post page template?

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to check what template is a single post type using?

I have a single post page and a single post portfolio page. Post page is `single.php` and portfolio is `single-portfoilo.php`. In my body I can see the classes loaded based on what page I'm on (what template is used).

I cannot use `is_page_template()`, because that will only work on pages, not posts. My alternative is to use `is_single()`, but that will target the regular posts, and I only want the portfolio posts to be targeted by the if clause.

Is there a workaround for this? It's really impractical :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like

```
if ( is_singular( 'portfolio' ) ) {
    // conditional content/code
}
```

Or if you have more than one custom post types you can insert an array like this

```
if ( is_singular( array( 'portfolio', 'book' ) ) ) {
    // conditional content/code
}
```